# Group by and find MAx value in a DataTable rows

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable

I have existing code that works very well and it finds the maximum value of a data column in the data table. Now I would like to refine this and find the maximum value per empid.
What change would be needed? I do not want to use LINQ.

I am right now using this:  memberSelectedTiers.Select("Insert_Date = MAX(Insert_Date)")
and I need to group it by Empid.

My code is as below.

```
        DataTable memberApprovedTiers = GetSupplierAssignedTiersAsTable(this.Customer_ID, this.Contract_ID);

        //get row with maximum Insert_Date in memberSelectedTiers
        DataRow msRow = null;
        if (memberSelectedTiers != null && memberSelectedTiers.Rows != null && memberSelectedTiers.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
           DataRow[]  msRows = memberSelectedTiers.Select("Insert_Date = MAX(Insert_Date)");
           if (msRows != null && msRows.Length > 0)
           {
               msRow = msRows[0];
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ to achieve this. I think the following will work (don't have VS to test):

```
var grouped = memberSelectedTiers.AsEnumerable()
                                 .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("EmpId"))
                                 .Select(grp => 
                                     new { 
                                         EmpId = grp.Key
                                       , MaxDate = grp.Max(e => e.Field<DateTime>("Insert_Date"))
                                     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Kelley, your answer helped me and that's great, but did you notice the OP stated he didn't want to use LINQ?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).